# Why the same IP of Cron Job in a App Engine is used by malicius requests?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I noticed this:
[image]

(Note that I deployed this service just 2 days ago and no one know it!!)

The only valid request here is the one to "/extract" at 4:10, because it is correct and it is at the scheduled time (of the cron job).
(You can also notice that the user agent is "AppEngine")

I created some routing for the "hacking try" paths to reply with a "F*** Y**".
Then I decided to use a dos.yaml file to define a blacklist.
I was taking note of the IPs and I noticed that the IP of the valid request is also used in this request (and probably other "malicious" ones):
[image]

I noticed that every execution of the my scheduled "cron job" (automated one or using "Run now") has a different IP. Also all the malicious requests have different IPs but you can see that some of them are executed programmatically:
 [image]

How is it possible?

My explanation is that Google Cloud Platform is hosting a lot of malicious services.

Also, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#Securing_URLs_for_Cron) says that cron jobs are issued by the IP 0.1.0.1.
[image]

Someone can explain me this unexpected behavior or where is the fault in my argument?

Alex